# Simulating small length in Micro for beam in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am simulating a very thin beam whose thickness is 2.5e-5 m, the simulation gives me that memory error. What I should consider while simulating dimensions like that given the fact I have to make dimensions uniform in SI units.

Comment: Dimensions are "completely" irrelevant for memory issues... The only thing that matters is the number of discretized elements in your simulation and consequently would you be able to allocate several arrays probably based on that number or not?